# Couchbase Multi-Server Setup Issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchbase

We have our couchbase server setup with three EC2 instances, first instance only has the database service running, second instance has the index service running & third instance has query service running.

The index & query servers are added to the data server using couchbase web console which has option to "Add Servers" under "Server Nodes" option referenced from [this](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/clustersetup/adding-nodes.html) article.

Now, for example, If I have to connect to the bucket residing on the server using Nodejs SDK, Ottoman and create a new user then it is able to connect to the bucket however it is not able to save the document in the bucket and gives me a "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

Please let us know if we need make any changes to the way servers are setup or how should we go ahead with above example so that we are able to create user.

Software Versions:
Couchbase : 4.5
Couchbase Nodejs SDK : 2.2
Ottoman : 1.0.3

This function is running from AWS Lambda using Nodejs ver-4.3.

The error I am getting is "Segmentation Fault(core dumped)".

Below is the AWS Lambda function that I have tried:

```
var couchbase=require('couchbase');
var ottoman=require('ottoman');
var config = require("./config");

var myCluster = new couchbase.Cluster(config.couchbase.server); // here tried connecting to either data / index / query server
ottoman.bucket = myCluster.openBucket(config.couchbase.bucket);

require('./models/users');

ottoman.ensureIndices(function(err) {
if (err) {
console.log('failed to created neccessary indices', err);
return;
}

console.log('ottoman indices are ready for use!');
});

var user = require('./models/users');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
user.computeHash(event.password, function(err, salt, hash) {
if (err) {
context.fail('Error in hash: ' + err);
} else {
user.createAndSave("userDetails details sent to the user creation function", function (error, done) {

            if (error) {
                context.fail(error.toString());
            }

            context.succeed({
                success: true,
                data: done
            });
        });
    }
});
};
```

When you run the above function locally (using node-lambda) to test it gives the same "Segmentation fault(core dumped)" error and when uploaded on Lambda and tested it gives the following error :

```
{
"errorMessage": "Process exited before completing request"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add in the software version numbers, sample code and the error output?

Comment: @kirk have updated the question with software version numbers, sample code & error output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue related to the MDS scenario you are using (https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/JSCBC-316).  This will be resolved in our next release in the beginning of August.